# How to use Microsoft icons in my add-in?

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I would like to use triangle icons from Microsoft
[fabric.min.css](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css) and
[fabric.components.min.css](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="ms-font-m">
    <div class="padding">
      <span class="ms-Icon--triangleRight"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the above code ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/voperiy/3/edit?html,output)) shows this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to show Microsoft's icons correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the ms-Icon class in order to use any of the specific icons. Here's the fixed line:

```
<span class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--triangleRight"></span>
```